# Cross-Origin Auth0 authentication

Tags: express, auth0

I’ve got my backend with the following endpoints authenticated with Auth0

```
api.mysite.com/auth/login
api.mysite.com/auth/logout
api.mysite.com/ → returns “logged in” or “logged out”
```

and my backend is an express server

On the other hand, if I pull up the console on my frontend which is on
mysite.com, `fetch(‘api.mysite.com’)` returns “logged out”
even if navigating to api.mysite.com in a new tab gives me “logged in”.

I whitelisted https://*.mysite.com under both “allowed web origins” and “allowed origins” and I can’t quite figure out why I can’t access my API.

Thanks in advance

[image]

It should be noted that I’m using universal login at api.mysite.com/auth/login

Answer (score 0):

heres my cors middelware

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";

const corsMiddleware = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const allowedDomains = [
    "http://localhost:4200",
    "https://sample.ir",
    "https://sample.ir"
  ];
  if (allowedDomains.indexOf(req.headers.origin) !== -1) {
    const index: number = allowedDomains.indexOf(req.headers.origin);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowedDomains[index]);
  }

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-API-KEY, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, observe, enctype, Content-Length, X-Csrf-Token");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

  // if (req.url.search("public") == -1) {
  //   res.header("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
  // }

  const method = req.method;
  if (method == "OPTIONS") {
    // res.header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK CORS");
    return res.status(200).json({});
  }
  next();

};

export default corsMiddleware;
```

Comment: my middle ware is wrong